# OpenVPN connects successfully but doesn't pass censorship!

Tags: 18.04, dns, openvpn

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and have just installed openVPN. when I run it and pass the credentials (in terminal) it connects successfully: (No error or something except for a warning for certificate verification)

```
Sun Aug 12 16:00:29 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun Aug 12 16:00:29 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080
Sun Aug 12 16:00:29 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sun Aug 12 16:00:29 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080 [nonblock]
Sun Aug 12 16:00:31 2018 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080
Sun Aug 12 16:00:31 2018 Send to HTTP proxy: 'CONNECT 127.0.0.1:443 HTTP/1.0'
Sun Aug 12 16:00:31 2018 Send to HTTP proxy: 'Host: 127.0.0.1'
Sun Aug 12 16:00:33 2018 HTTP proxy returned: 'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established'
Sun Aug 12 16:00:35 2018 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Sun Aug 12 16:00:35 2018 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080
Sun Aug 12 16:00:36 2018 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080, sid=2187abbb 60e49570
Sun Aug 12 16:00:36 2018 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Sun Aug 12 16:00:40 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=Next
Sun Aug 12 16:00:40 2018 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
Sun Aug 12 16:00:43 2018 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1.2 ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 384 bit EC, curve: secp384r1
Sun Aug 12 16:00:43 2018 [server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS:7080
Sun Aug 12 16:00:45 2018 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 SENT CONTROL [server]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8,dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4,route 10.7.0.1,topology net30,ping 15,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.7.2.18 10.7.2.17,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: peer-id set
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: adjusting link_mtu to 1626
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 OPTIONS IMPORT: data channel crypto options modified
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 Data Channel: using negotiated cipher 'AES-256-GCM'
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-256-GCM' initialized with 256 bit key
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 ROUTE_GATEWAY Router_IP_Address/255.255.255.0 IFACE=wlp2s0 HWADDR=48:d2:24:37:87:5d
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 local 10.7.2.18 peer 10.7.2.17
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip route add EXTERNAL_IP-ADDRESS/32 via 192.168.1.1
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.2.17
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.7.2.17
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 /sbin/ip route add 10.7.0.1/32 metric 1 via 10.7.2.17
Sun Aug 12 16:00:50 2018 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And when I google 'my ip address' it shows my new IP but I cannot open blocked websites such as youtube or facebook. (Unfortunately they're blocked in my country!)

**EDIT:** It turns out to be DNS leak problem!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear - you aren't connecting to your own server in a country where the websites are blocked, right? You are connecting to a server in a country where the websites are not blocked?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, yes when I try "my IP address" on google, it shows the address provided by tun0 (e.g., somewhere in New Jersey, US).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled a lot for two days long and realized (via [dnsleaktest.com](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/)) I had DNS leak porblem. [This blog](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/09/how-to-fix-openvpn-dns-leak-in-linux.html) and [this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS) helped me pretty much so I first installed:

```
sudo apt install openresolv
```

and then added:

```
--script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

to the bottom of my openvpn config file and now it works like a charm! FYI, I only run openvpn from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to disable IPv6? I guess your computer is trying to connect to the website over IPv6 and you are only routing traffic via your VPN over IPv4. I encountered more or less the same problem.

You can check on: https://whatismyipaddress.com/

Afterwards, it should only show your VPN IPv4 address.

Comment: I check my IP status (via http://ipv6-test.com) and it says IPv4 supported (with the same IP address that my openvpn claims) and IPv6 not supported. So what should I do next?